# How to share a class object in Java?

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE to create a system.

I created an instance of a class, then I want to access this instance from a different JSwing Form. I declared the class as public, but it still doesn't recognize the instance.

Any help?

Regards..

Comment: Your description is somewhat vague. Please post code.

Comment: I'm gathering inputs from user in a form, I'm saving the inputs in a class instance. Then on the next form, I want to display those inputs. So I have to access the class instance from the previous form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass this instance to your Form either in Form Constructor or by a method.

or you can make class (class of your instance) a singleton class and use a single instance in your forms.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need static fields and/or methods in your class.